# How to unsubscribe an events subscription

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, events

I am using events to subscribe an event in my ionic 3 application. It seems there are two ways to unsubscribe the subscription as given in the `unsubscription1()` and `unsubscription2()`

Could you please tell what is the difference of these two methods? are both of them can unsubscribe the subscription as expected?

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
    ...

    messageSubscription: any

    constructor(private events: Events ...){
      ...
    }
    
    subscription(){
      messageSubscription = this.events.subscription("newmessage", () => {
      ...
      }
    }
    
    unsubscription1(){
      this.events.unsubscription("newmessage")
    }
    
    unsubscription2(){
      messageSubscription.unsubscribe()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As per the [Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/util/Events/), there are no `.subscription` and `.unsubscription` methods on `Events`
- There are only `.subscribe(<eventname>, () => {})` and `.unsubscribe(<eventname>, () => {})`
- `this.events.subscribe(<event>, () => {})` return type is `void`.
- So `messageSubscription` variable holds nothing and events won't get unsubscribed in the below code

> unsubscription2() {
> messageSubscription.unsubscribe(); }

So the correct code for subscribing and unsubscribing is below

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
...

constructor(private events: Events...) {
  ...
}

subscription() {
  this.events.subscribe("newmessage", () => {
    ...
  });
}

unsubscription1() {
  this.events.unsubscribe("newmessage")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a variable for destroy condition

```
public destroyed = new Subject();
```

Add ngDestroy lifecycle hook

```
ngOnDestroy() {
      this.destroyed.next();
      this.destroyed.complete();
    }
```

And use takeUntil(). Using an operator like takeUntil instead of manually unsubscribing will also complete the observable, triggering any completion event on the observable.

```
   this.events.
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed))
   subscription("newmessage", () => {
  ...
  }
```